# Как правильно составить очередь в rxJava и ретрофит

Tags: rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Я использую ретрофит2 и рх2

Мое приложение раз в секунду делает запрос на сервер

Я хочу эти запросы поставить в синхронную очередь, так чтоб они выполнялись один за другим по мере поступления в очередь

Вот мой `flowable`

```
private fun doOnRunActionRequest(runner: Runner)
{
    val runnerFlowable: Flowable<RunActionResponse> = mRunActionEndpoint.postRunActivity(runner)
}
```

Этот метод вызывается 1 раз в секунду

Вот, что я сделал

Во первых для поддержки бекпрещур создал вот такой процессор

```
private val runnerActionProcessor = PublishProcessor.create<Flowable<RunActionResponse>>()
```

Потом вот так на него подписываюсь

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun onStart()
{
    runnerActionProcessor //
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()) //
            .subscribe({ iVal ->
                iVal.subscribeBy( //
                        onNext = { response ->
                            AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, "TAG", "response ${Thread.currentThread().name} :: response ${response.success}")
                        }, //
                        onError = { error -> AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, "TAG", "error ${Thread.currentThread().name} :: response ${error.message}") }, //
                        onComplete = {} //
                )
            })
}
```

И вот так добавил строчку в метод `doOnRunRequest()`

```
private fun doOnRunActionRequest(runner: Runner)
{
    val runnerFlowable: Flowable<RunActionResponse> = mRunActionEndpoint.postRunActivity(runner)
    runnerActionProcessor.onNext(runnerFlowable)
}
```

Но судя по логам, выполнение идет все равно в разных потоках

```
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-1 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-2 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-3 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-4 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-5 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-6 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-7 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-8 :: response timeout
  RxCachedThreadScheduler-9 :: response timeout
```

Я вот не совсем пойму как правильно так сделать, чтоб каждый запрос складывался в очередь один за другим и выполнялся последовательно

Если, что то пропустил спрашивайте

Comment: как решили проблему?